# validating nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Why is the validations in `ResourceAllocation` is not called?

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base 
         has_many :resource_allocations
         accepts_nested_attributes_for :resource_allocations
         validates_associated :resource_allocations
    end


class ResourceAllocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee

  validate :location_id, :presence => true
  validate :department_id, :presence => true
  validate :period_from, :presence => true
  validate :period_to, :presence => true
  validate :allocation, :presence => true, :numericality => true
end
```